Google Slides - Replace Objects and Tables from new spreadsheet
I hope you're all doing well!
I usually duplicate Google Slides presentations that have linked data from a database on Google Sheets.
To do this, I duplicate the presentation, and then I duplicate the spreadsheet. Then, I run this script to replace the charts from the old spreadsheet with the new one:
//this updates all charts embedded from sheets on all slides of the specified slides id to a specified spreadsheet id

//Intended for use immediately after duplicating both the slide/presentation and the spreadsheet

//For now you must manually enter / cut and paste the ID of both files directly below in the two Id variables inside the quotes

function myFunction() {

//sheet and slide id's - the charts in the slide id listed here will be linked to the the sheet id listed here:

var slideId="435345345345345345345345345345345345"; // enter your slide id here

var spreadsheetId="23423423423423423423423423423434234234"; // enter your sheet id here

var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);

var sheet2=ss2.getSheets()[0];

var chart2=sheet2.getCharts()[0];

Logger.log('spreadsheet2 name is ' + ss2.getName());

//get all charts from all sheets of the spreadsheet copy

var sheets2=ss2.getSheets();

var allCharts=[];//keep track of all charts on all sheets of the spreadsheet

var allChartsIds=[];//keep track of the ids for all the charts

var chartsnum=0;

for (var i = 0; i < sheets2.length; i++) {

var curSheet2=sheets2[i];

var charts2 = curSheet2.getCharts();

for (var j = 0; j < charts2.length; j++) {

var curChart2=charts2[j];

allCharts[chartsnum]=curChart2;

allChartsIds[chartsnum]=curChart2.getChartId();

chartsnum++;

Logger.log('\n chart2 Id is ' + curChart2.getChartId());

}

}

//total number of charts in all sheets of the spreadsheet

var lengthAllCharts=allCharts.length;

var pres2 = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);

Logger.log('pres2 name is ' + pres2.getName());

var slides2=pres2.getSlides();

for (var i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++) {

var curSlide2=slides2[i];

var charts2 = curSlide2.getSheetsCharts();

for (var j = 0; j < charts2.length; j++) {

var curChart2=charts2[j];

var chartHeight=curChart2.getHeight();

var chartWidth=curChart2.getWidth();

var chartLeft=curChart2.getLeft();

var chartTop=curChart2.getTop();

for (var k = 0; k < lengthAllCharts; k++) {

if (curChart2.getChartId()==allChartsIds[k]){

var chart2=allCharts[k];

break;

}

}

Logger.log('\n chart2 ObjId is ' + curChart2.getObjectId());

Logger.log('\n chart2 ChartId is ' + curChart2.getChartId());

Logger.log('\n chart2 Chart data ' + curChart2.getSpreadsheetId());

curChart2.remove();

curSlide2.insertSheetsChart(chart2, chartLeft, chartTop, chartWidth, chartHeight);

}

}

}


However, it doesn't update the links for objects that aren't charts. For example, tables and titles. Could someone help me implement this script (or create a new one) that does this for the other objects?
Thank you guys!

Someone? Anyone?
